# How can I import libraries from another Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I made a new environment in my Anaconda and I installed some libraries in it, but now I can't import them in Spyder. How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder

Comment: This  helper https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder  from the Spyder team has a step by step troubleshooter.

Comment: Spyder is part of conda env. A conda env has to install spyder at first if you want to use spyder. Launch Anaconda navigator, switch conda env and install spyder for it.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have installed the libraries into your new environment and not somewhere else. You can add the libraries that you need either in Anaconda Navigator (make sure you're in the right environment, then look for 'Not Installed' libraries, select the ones you need, and install them).

Alternatively, you can go to the command line and enter:

```
conda activate your-environment-name
conda install pandas numpy (or whatever your list of missing libraries is)
```

You can check which libraries are installed with `conda list`

If, after all that, you can't import them in Spyder, you may be running Spyder in the wrong virtual environment. If you're starting Spyder from the command line, ensure you've done the above `conda activate` first. Alternatively, start Spyder from Anaconda Navigator, but again, ensure you have selected the correct environment.